# Is this a finite dimensional $L(t)$-algebra?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

I recently read this argument in a book:

> $k$ is a field, $L|k$ is a field extension, $K$ is a finite extension of $k(t)$. This implies that $K\otimes_kL$ is a finite dimensional $L(t)$-algebra.

But this doesn't seem right. If $L|k$ is algebraic, then I think we would have $k(t)\otimes_kL=L(t)$, but does this hold in general? It feels like this should be obvious but my field theory is a bit rusty...

Comment: How do you define a structure of $L(t)$-algebra on $K\otimes_kL$?

Comment: @user26857 In general that would be hard. But if you see the answer below, there is an obvious map to $L(t)$ (send $t$ to $t$ and elements of $L$ to $L$). If this is an isomorphism it has an inverse, and this inverse gives the algebra structure.

Comment: I've thought your question is "in general". Or, in general, I have troubles seeing how the tensor product is an $L(t)$-algebra. For instance, I can't even see it for $K=k(t)$.

Comment: @user26857 I think that the reason you can't see it is because it isn't true. The thing I asked about was probably missing some assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a natural map $\phi:k(t)\otimes_k L\to L(t)$. As you say, it
is an isomorphism when $L/k$ is algebraic, but not in general.
Take, say $k=\Bbb Q$ and $L=\Bbb R$. Then $1/(t-\pi)$ is not
in the image of $\phi$,

Comment: Thanks! If I'm reading it correctly, this gives that $K\otimes L$ is a finite $L(t)$-algebra for an algebraic $L|k$. Follow up-question: is this assumption necessary for it to be a finite dimensional such algebra? I.e. "is the implication in the question wrong?"